# Checks if all nested objects don't have 'status' attribute as 'deleted'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently this code working, but its performance is very poor — 1.45 seconds seems a bit too much for a simple recursive if statement that only checks attribute values.

```
def _check_delete_status(self, obj) -> bool:

    obj_name = obj._sa_class_manager.class_.__name__
    self.visited.append(obj_name)
    
    if getattr(obj, 'status', 'deleted').lower() != 'deleted':

        children = [parent for parent in self._get_parents(self._get_table_by_table_name(obj_name)) if parent not in self.visited]

        for child in children:
            if (child_obj := getattr(obj, child, None)) and child not in self.visited:
                if self._check_delete_status(child_obj):
                    return True
    else:
        return True
    return False
```

Although `self._get_parents` seems like a counterintuitive name (it's used elsewhere in the code), in this case it is still very useful to this solution: It returns a list with all possible attribute names that object might have as children. For example, an object named `appointment` will have `['patient', 'schedule']` as response; of which `patient` will have `[]` since it doesn't have any children, and `schedule` will have `['physiotherapist', 'address', 'patient', 'service']` returned.

When those values are then used on `getattr(object, child_name)` it returns the object corresponding to the child.

I tried to think on how to do this iteratively, but couldn't up come with any solutions.

PS: The reason for the `self.visited` list, is that sometimes an object might have the exact same object nested inside, and since they have the same values they can be skipped.

**EDIT:** The "helper" methods:

```
def _get_table_by_table_name(self, table_name: str) -> Table:
    return self._all_models[table_name]['table']
```

```
@staticmethod
def _get_parents(table: Table) -> set:
    parents = set()
    if table.foreign_keys:
        for fk in table.foreign_keys:
            parent_name = fk.column.table.name
            parents.add(parent_name) if parent_name != table.name else None
    return parents
```

Comment: This is a class method - so please show the whole class.

Comment: @Reinderien The whole class is a bit too big, but I've included the other methods used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is improperly using lists.

> ```py
> children = [parent for parent in self._get_parents(self._get_table_by_table_name(obj_name)) if parent not in self.visited]
> ```

By using a list comprehension you *have* to generate every parent *before* you can validate a parent. Lets instead use say you want to know if 0 is in `range(1_000_000)`. What your code would be doing is building a list of 1 million numbers *before* you check the first value is 0.

You should use a generator expression, or just use standard `for` loops, to build `children` so we can exit early. (Of course doing so would rely on `self._get_parents` and `self._get_table_by_table_name` not returning lists. Which I don't have access to, so cannot comment on.)

> ```py
> self.visited.append(obj_name)
> ```
>
> ```py
> parent not in self.visited
> ```
>
> ```py
> child not in self.visited
> ```

We know `self.visited` is a list. So we know `in` runs in \$O(n)\$ time. You want to instead use a set which runs in \$O(1)\$ time.

---

Ignoring changing `self.visited` to a set you can simplify the code using `any` and a generator expression.

```py
def _check_delete_status(self, obj) -> bool:
    obj_name = obj._sa_class_manager.class_.__name__
    self.visited.append(obj_name)
    if getattr(obj, 'status', 'deleted').lower() == 'deleted':
        return True
    else:
        return any(
            child not in self.visited
            and (child_obj := getattr(obj, child, None))
            and child not in self.visited
            and self._check_delete_status(child_obj)
            for child in self._get_parents(self._get_table_by_table_name(obj_name))
        )
```

You should also notice you don't need `child not in self.visited` twice.

Comment: While this does make the code way cleaner, it still took the same 1.45 seconds (even after changing `self.visited` to a set). Should I assume this happens for another reason?

Comment: Making a quick perf_counter shows this:
`Now at patient: Time since start -> 0.0 seconds`
`Now at appointment: Time since start -> 0.0001 seconds`
`Now at schedule: Time since start -> 0.3194 seconds`
`Now at service: Time since start -> 0.5754 seconds`
`Now at organization: Time since start -> 0.8869 seconds`
`Now at physiotherapist: Time since start -> 1.312 seconds`
`Now at address: Time since start -> 1.5363 seconds`

Comment: @ViniciusF. If you've made all the changes I suggested (including removing the duplicate `child not in self.visited` and ensuring both `_get_parents` and `_get_table_by_table_name` do not return lists) then I, or anyone else, can't improve the performance of your code as you have not provided the code which has the performance issue.

Comment: Yeah, thought so. I'm guessing this is a job for the cProfile then. But much appreciated for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

I should've done this before, but I ran cProfile on my function and discovered that what was making it slow was totally unrelated to it being recursive or anything: SQLAlchemy was performing lazy-loading so it had to send some requests to get all relationships it needed which slowed my function down quite a bit.

After I added `lazy='immediate'` to my `mapper` parameters it ran smoothly under 0.0006 seconds.

Nevertheless, the code optimization suggested by Peilonrayz was quite useful and definitely implemented.